# Hide a value or text from the HTML Input control

Tags: html, html-input, htmlcontrols

How to hide a text or value from a html inputfield without set to hidden control. I want to the textbox keep on visible but the text/value is hide. Is possible?

Thank You

Comment: `<input type='password'>`

Comment: @zer00ne I mean hide the value/text to be visible look like empty string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this solution

you can set text color to transparent

```
 input {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: This should be added for when it's selected and highlighted by user `input::selection {
  background: transparent; 
}`
`input::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent; 
}`

Comment: or at last textbox background color and font-color ... make both same white color